# IE ERROR 'object doesn't support this property or method'

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I have the following bit of code:

```
/* Set registered Cookie to TRUE if uri is  /registrationSuccess */
var path = document.location.pathname.toLowerCase();
var re = new RegExp("/registrationSuccess","i");
if (re.test(path )) {
    $.cookie("fpsRegistered", "true", { path: '/'});
}
/* End of cookie reg */
```

This line is causing IE to Error 'object doesn't support this property or method'

```
var path = document.location.pathname.toLowerCase();
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Use `window.location` instead: `var path = window.location.pathname.toLowerCase();`

Comment: `document.location.pathname.toLowerCase();` works for me in IE6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [the documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp) for the `document` object, there is no "location" property, but there is a `url` property, so you should be coding:

```
   var path = document.url.toLowerCase();
```